# How to dynamically add group row labels with kableExtra in R

Tags: r, kableextra

I have a data frame (example below) that I'd like to put into an HTML table using the package `kableExtra` in R. One of my columns (`pos`) is a grouping variable, and I'd like to use this to add group row labels in the table. I know I can do this with the `pack_rows()` function from `kableExtra`, but I'd like to know if there's some way of doing this dynamically. For example, I have three unique string values for `pos` in the example data set and I could easily call three `pack_rows()` functions and supply the respective indices (first value and the mean row). However, I may not always have three unique `pos` strings (e.g., sometimes I may have two, four, or five), and the number of rows/observations for each group will change in my real data set. As I'd like to use this to generate a report, I'm hoping there is a trick to automating this process somehow. Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(10)
name <- paste("Name", LETTERS[1:15])
var1 <- rep(rnorm(15, 100, 20))
var2 <- rep(rnorm(15, 100, 20))
var3 <- rep(rnorm(15, 100, 20))
var4 <- rep(rnorm(15, 100, 20))
pos <- c(rep("DEF", 5), rep("MID", 5), rep("FWD", 5))

df <- data.frame(name, var1, var2, var3, var4, pos)

agg_df <- bind_rows(
  df,
  df %>% group_by(pos) %>%
    summarise_at(vars(var1:var4), mean) %>%
      mutate(name = "mean")
  ) %>% 
  arrange(pos, name)

agg_df %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"),
                fixed_thead = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `Reduce` or `purrr::reduce` to add the header rows via `pack_rows()`. To this end I first create a list containing the group `start` and `end` rows as well as the group `label`.

```
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)

row_groups <- agg_df |>
  mutate(row = row_number()) |>
  select(pos, row) |>
  split(~pos) |>
  lapply(\(x) {
    data.frame(
      label = unique(x$pos),
      start = min(x$row),
      end = max(x$row)
    )
  })

agg_df |>
  select(-pos) |>
  kbl() |>
  kable_styling(
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"),
    fixed_thead = TRUE
  ) |>
  Reduce(
    \(x, y) pack_rows(x, y$label, y$start, y$end),
    x = row_groups,
    init = _
  )
```

[image]